# Full screen image background on header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make website layout with css and Bootstrap.

I have tried with Foundataion FW and I got what I want. But, when I switch to Bootstrap and use same code like before. The result is different.

I want to layout header full screen with image as background like this site http://ottavio.kleis.agency/index.html.

Here's my custom css:

```
.intro{
background-image: url(../img/asset/new_bg.jpg);
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-size: cover;
```

}

HTML:

```
    <div class="row intro">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h1 class="h2-cover">Ingin belajar Qur'an <strong>gratis?</strong></h1>
            <p class="line-cover">
                Kami akan berikan pelatihan baca Qur'an gratis sepanjang yang Anda mau.
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="button round alert">Mau!</a>
            <a href="#" class="button round morelighter">Benarkah?</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problems are:

1. Image not full screen
2. Next div (e.g. Nav, article) isn't below on the div with class .intro. But, it's inside the div (class intro).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution for you.

**problem 1)** 
What I did is I added a `<img>` below the first div (so the div with the class intro). The img has a clas of `bg`.

Than add this css:

```
.bg{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/kmfexz52/2/) you have a working fiddle. I added a lot of `<br>` tags to show you it works.

You can also try to set the background image `height:100%` and `width:auto;`. If you do this the image won't be so crammed together on some screens.

**problem 2)** 
I Gave every slide a class `slide1`. I also added to all the slide classes `position:relative;`. Taka a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52ubgwye/1/).

i hope your question is now anwsered. If you have other problems, feel free to ask.

Comment: The problem number one is solved!

But, The number two is still problem. I can't make div below the first div (with class intro).

Please check the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/kmfexz52/4/. I have give an example.

Comment: @Surahman So if I uderstand it right. You want that the red div is placed under the intro div. so that you can make more slides like the intro.

Comment: that's right! I want to placed the red div under the intro div. But, not for make more slides. I just want to add another div like article, footer, etc.

Comment: @Surahman take a look at my answer to problem 2. It should be enough fro you to continue your site development. If not take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/52ubgwye/2/ . This is a fiddle With an article instead of a slide

Comment: you solved this! Thank you so much. I have been wasted my time over 5 hours to tried.

Comment: @Surahman no problem. I know the feeling that if you cannot solve something you really need. Taka a look at this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position if you want to know more about css `position`