# My <article> get on top of my intro background

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm stuck in my website development...
I would like to add a `<article>` after my `<header>` which contains a full screen background intro, but the section stacks on top of my `<div>` even if it's in the header and my article in my `<body>`.
I saw [Full screen image background on header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644511/full-screen-image-background-on-header) but didn't resolved my problem...

Here is my code :

**css**

```
body{
  margin:0;
}
.intro{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /*background-size: cover;*/

}
.text-intro{
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-left: 5%;
}
.bg{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;

}
h1{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 42px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
article h2{
  color: white;
}
header h2{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.3;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
.btn-intro a{
  display: block;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFEA00;
  border: solid #FFEA00 2px;
  width: 379px;
  padding: 21px;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;

}
.btn-intro a:hover{
  display: block;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: #FFEA00;
  border: solid #FFEA00 2px;
  width: 379px;
  padding: 21px;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
}
.social img{
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
article{
  position: relative;
}
```

**html**

```
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="intro">
      <img class="bg" src="images/bg-intro.png">
      <div class="text-intro">
        <div class="social">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/WarexStudio"><img src="images/facebook.svg" alt="Facebook"></a>
          <a href="https://www.twitter.com/KoenigTheo"><img src="images/twitter.svg" alt="Twitter"></a>
        </div>
        <h2>Portraits des membres du groupe A1</h2>
        <h1>Theo Koenig</h1>
        <h2>MMi Montbéliard</h2>
        <div class="btn-intro">
          <a href="">VOIR LES PORTRAITS</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <article>
    <h2>Groupe de TP A1</h2>
  </article>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you put a picture of the result you wants ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    .text-intro{
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
```

After that try playing around with the "top" and left" values to get the positioning you want in lieu of the padding in your previous declaration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes that's what I want. But this make my .text-intro display below my background :(

Comment: Gotcha, check the revised answer hopefully that works :D

Comment: This is working for my .text-intro, but my <article> remains on top of my background :( Here is what I get : http://www.cjoint.com/data/FCrpibuVsqO_capture.png

Comment: @TheFredStar It would help if you explain what you are doing, which you should, instead of just trying to give him the answer, which is not what SO is about.