# Bootstrap - full screen header image followed by background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

New at Bootstrap. I'm having a problem setting my background image to follow the header image.

The header section has it's own full-screen background, which I then want to be followed by a tiled background image.

I tried:

```
<div class="header">...</div>

<div class="main-body">
    <div class="container">...</div>
    <div class="container">...</div>
    ...
</div>

<div class="footer">...</div>
```

with the following stylesheet:

```
.main-body {
    text-align: center;
    background: url(../img/setttings-bg-black.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 1024;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    background: url(../img/promo-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The problem is that the main-body background's top is hidden by the bottom part of the header body.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without knowing the dimensions of the images it may be difficult to diagnose the problem. Could you set up an interactive example by editing your question and using the snippet feature (shortcut: Ctrl + M) with the images included?

Comment: Look at css positioning

Answer (score 0):

Verify this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644511/full-screen-image-background-on-header) or [link](http://jsfiddle.net/52ubgwye/1/)

have a solution for you.

problem 1) 
What I did is I added a `<img>` below the first div (so the div with the class intro). The img has a clas of `bg`.

Than add this css:

```
.bg{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

here you have a working fiddle. I added a lot of `<br>` tags to show you it works.

You can also try to set the background image `height:100%` and `width:auto;`. If you do this the image won't be so crammed together on some screens.

problem 2) 
I Gave every slide a class slide1. I also added to all the slide classes `position:relative;`. Taka a look at this fiddle.

i hope your question is now anwsered. If you have other problems, feel free to ask.